# Spring security Freemarker Session is null or missing

Tags: spring-security, freemarker

I'm trying to use Session object in Freemarker template:

```
<#assign
known = Session.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT??
>

<#if known>
    <#assign
    user = Session.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT.authentication.principal
    name = user.getUsername()
    isAdmin = user.isAdmin()
    currentUserId = user.getId()
    >
<#else>
    <#assign
    name = "unknown"
    isAdmin = false
    currentUserId = -1
    >
</#if>
```

but receive the error:

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> Session  [in template "parts/security.ftlh" at line 2, column 9]
```

How could I use the Session object in Freemarker? Is another method exists to hide some HTML elements based on user roles?

Answer (score 1):

Add `spring.freemarker.expose-session-attributes=true` to the `application.properties`

And modify your code to:

```
<#assign
    known = SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT??
>
    
<#if known>
    <#assign
        user = SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT.authentication.principal
        name = user.getUsername()
        isAdmin = user.isAdmin()
        currentUserId = user.getId()
    >
<#else>
    <#assign
        name = "unknown"
        isAdmin = false
        currentUserId = -1
    >
</#if>
```